# Saving lot of data sets automatically

Tags: r

I am creating 22 data sets, and each data set has a matrix with 3 columns and 3 rows. I trying to save the 22 data sets automatically in my working directory, but my codes didn't work.

Hers is my codes:

```
A<-array(0,dim=c(3,3,22))
for ( iter in 1:22)
{
x<-rnorm(9,0,1)
y<-matrix(x,ncol=3,byrow=T)
A[,,iter]<-y
filename1 <- paste (" A",1:22 ,".csv ", sep ="")
write.table( A[,,iter]  , file = filename1 , row.names =FALSE ,col.names = FALSE )
}
```

It gave me a message:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
>     invalid 'description' argument
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Could someone please help me?

Comment: `print(filename1)` should reveal your problem right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the file name  should probably be `filename1 <- paste0("A", iter, ".csv")`; using 1:22 will make 22 file names at once.